# Joining Pandas Dataframes on shared indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 `DataFrames` that have differing numbers of shared indexes. For example:

```
>>> df0=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3,4],[2011,2012],['A','B']], names=['Season','Year','Location']))
>>> df0['Value0']=np.random.randint(1,100,len(df0))
>>> 
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2011,2012],['A','B']], names=['Year','Location']))
>>> df1['Value1']=np.random.randint(1,100,len(df1))
>>> 
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B'])
>>> df2.index.name='Location'
>>> df2['Value2']=np.random.randint(1,100,len(df2))
>>> df0
                      Value0
Season Year Location        
1      2011 A             18
            B             63
       2012 A             88
            B             30
2      2011 A             35
            B             60
       2012 A             61
            B              4
3      2011 A             70
            B              9
       2012 A             11
            B             38
4      2011 A             68
            B             57
       2012 A             13
            B             35
>>> df1
               Value1
Year Location        
2011 A             22
     B             74
2012 A             73
     B             44
>>> df2
          Value2
Location        
A             70
B             85
>>>
```

I am looking for the best way to join them on their common indexes.

Things I have tried:

1) `pd.concat([df0,df1,df2],1)` would be nice because it accepts a list of dataframes, but this appears to only work if the dataframes have the same number of indexes.

2) Joining either of the multiindex dataframes with the single index `DataFrame` works: `df1.join(df2)` or `df0.join(df2)`. However joining the `DataFrame` with two indexes with the `DataFrame` with three indexes does not: `df0.join(df1)` and gives me the following error: "NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented"

At this point, the approach I have been taking is to reset the indexes and use `pd.merge()`. See below:

```
def JoinMulti(DFList):
    FinalDF=DFList[0].reset_index()
    for OtherDF in DFList[1:]:
        FinalDF=pd.merge(FinalDF, OtherDF.reset_index(), how='outer')

    #Now I want reindex it so that it's indexed the same as the `DataFrame` with the highest number of levels
    NLevels=[x.index.nlevels for x in DFList]
    MaxIndexPos=NLevels.index(max(NLevels))
    FinalIndex=DFList[MaxIndexPos].index
    FinalDF=FinalDF.set_index(FinalIndex.names).reindex(FinalIndex)
    return FinalDF

>>> JoinMulti([df0,df1,df2])
                      Value0  Value1  Value2
Season Year Location                        
1      2011 A             43       5      96
            B             63      46      97
       2012 A             68       6      96
            B             23      99      97
2      2011 A             66       5      96
            B             30      46      97
       2012 A             45       6      96
            B             79      99      97
3      2011 A             66       5      96
            B             21      46      97
       2012 A             86       6      96
            B             11      99      97
4      2011 A             95       5      96
            B             58      46      97
       2012 A             32       6      96
            B             80      99      97
>>>
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Are there any improvements that could be made or any exceptions that I'm forgetting about?

Answer (score 1):

I modified solution by Stefan Jansen:

```
def jez(df0,df1,df2):
    df1 = df1.join(df2)
    df0 = df0.reset_index('Season')
    FinalDF = df0.join(df1).set_index('Season', append=True).reorder_levels(['Season', 'Year', 'Location']).sortlevel()
    return FinalDF

print jez(df0,df1,df2)
```

Timing:

```
In [41]: %timeit jez(df0,df1,df2)
The slowest run took 4.14 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.02 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit JoinMulti([df0,df1,df2])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.83 ms per loop
```